# How to download Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview (not Enterprise Edition)

Tags: visual-studio

I tried to download the 2019 Community *Edition* from Microsoft but their website wants me to have Enterprise Edition, only. Can someone please provide me a url to the VS Community 2019 Preview?

Comment: I think it's just 'Enterprise'

Comment: The question is, if I start using 2019 Preview and build an app and then want to use 2019 Community if there is one will I be tied into buying a pro edition?

Answer (score 1):

You can download Visual Studio 2019 RC from
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/es/downloads/
[image]
DL https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=16

[UPDATE]

Today (April 2nd) Visual Studio 2019 has been released, just head to https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ and download.

[image]